# Popup not firing for all markers in leafletjs

Tags: leaflet, markers

I am using bindpopups to show a popup on a marker. This is a poc for showing markers on the map which has 2 markers at present but it seems like it fires only on one marker and not the second one. Whats wrong with the code?

```html
<html style='height: 100%; width: 100%;'>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="src/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/L.Control.Sidebar.css" />

<style>
    body {
        padding: 30px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    #sidebar {
        padding: 24px;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        float: right;            
        font-family: monospace;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

     <div id="sidebar">
        <span style="font-weight: bold;">Filter</span><br>            
        <input backgroundColor="red" type="radio" name="filter" value="schedule" > Schedule<br>            
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="risk"> Risk<br>
        <input type="radio" name="filter" value="opm"> OPM<br>  
        <input  type="radio" name="filter" value="location"> Location<br>  
        <input  type="radio" name="filter" value="all" checked> All<br>  
    </div>    

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="src/L.Control.Sidebar.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {                
         $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
                //alert(this.value);
            });     

        });        

        var map;
        var poiData = [{
            "id" : "142065",
            "color": "green",
            "address" : "5 Rue de l'Arcade, 11400 Castelnaudary, France",
            "description" : "",
            "lat" : "51.47344681882283",
            "lon" : "-0.29162660006234",
            "name" : "Le Petit ",
            "zoom_show" : "2",
            "recommended" : true
        }, {
            "id" : "15555",
            "color": "blue",
            "address" : "5 Rue de l'Arcade, 11400 Castelnaudary, France",
            "description" : "",
            "lat" : "51.47344681882283",
            "lon" : "-0.3091066283535285",
            "name" : "Le Petit Gazouilli",
            "zoom_show" : "2"
        }];       

        window.onresize = function() {
            Ti.API.info('********** RESIZE FUNCTION IS CALLED1!!!!! window.innerHeight' + window.innerHeight + ' //// document.body.clientHeight = ' + document.body.clientHeight);
            // outputs window.innerheight =
            document.getElementById("map").style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
            // maybe change this to html/body tag to let it be a more generic fix.
            map.invalidateSize();
            // relevant to your leaflet map to trigger resizing / redrawing /filling.
        };

        var path = "",
            obj = "",
            center = "",
            bounds = "",
            minZoomLevel = "",
            maxZoomLevel = "";
        /*
        Ti.App.addEventListener("app:startWebview", function(e) {
            obj = JSON.parse(e.pois);
            center = JSON.parse(e.center);
            minZoomLevel = JSON.parse(e.minZoomLevel);
            maxZoomLevel = JSON.parse(e.maxZoomLevel);
            bounds = JSON.parse(e.bounds);
            createMap();

        });*/
            obj = poiData;
            center = [51.478744, -0.295573];                
            minZoomLevel = 16;
            maxZoomLevel = 18;
            //bounds = [[51.470103, -0.310407], [51.478376, -0.280567]];
            bounds = [[51.470103, -0.310407], [51.486674, -0.286572]]; //sw,ne

            createMap();

        function createMap() {
            //alert('2s');

            var points = obj;
            map = L.map('map', {
                //center : [51.47834563230677, -0.29832356080899747],
                //layers: [tileLayer['Gray'], groupA, groupB], 
                center : center,
                zoom : minZoomLevel,
                zoomControl : true                    
            });


            var tl = L.tileLayer('mapTiles/richmond/{z}_{x}_{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6IjZjNmRjNzk3ZmE2MTcwOTEwMGY0MzU3YjUzOWFmNWZhIn0.Y8bhBaUMqFiPrDRW9hieoQ', {
                minZoom : minZoomLevel,
                maxZoom : maxZoomLevel,
                bounds : bounds,
                //maxNativeZoom : 14,
                unloadInvisibleTiles : true,
                id : 'mapbox.streets'

            }).addTo(map);


            map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

    var sidebar = L.control.sidebar('sidebar', {            
        closeButton: false,
        position: 'right'
    });
    map.addControl(sidebar);
     sidebar.show();

    setTimeout(function () {
        sidebar.show();
    }, 500);
    tl.on("load",function() { 
        //alert("all visible tiles have been loaded");
});
            var poiLayer,
                indicatorMarker;

            var indicatorIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl : "images/gps_indicator_med.png",
                iconRetinaUrl : "images/gps_indicator_med.png",
                iconSize : [140, 140],
                iconAnchor : [70, 70]
            });

            indicatorMarker = L.marker([0, 0], {
                icon : indicatorIcon,
                zIndexOffset : 0,
                clickable : false
            }).addTo(map);

            /*
             function showPoi(item, zoom) {
             if (item.base) {
             return true;
             }

             if (item.zoom_show == "1.0") {
             return true;
             }
             if (item.zoom_show == "2.0" && zoom >= 16) {
             return true;
             }
             if (zoom >= 14) {
             return true;
             } else {
             return false;
             }
             }
             */

            function onClick(e) {
                alert('clicked a poi! ');
                //Ti.API.info("click " + JSON.stringify(e.target.options.item));
                // if (e && e.target && e.target.options && e.target.options.item) {
                // alert('clicked a poi!');
                // Ti.App.fireEvent("app:openPoi", {
                // poiItem : JSON.stringify(e.target.options.item)
                // });
                // }
            }

            var zoomFactor = 0.8;
            function addPois(zoom) {
                var poiArray = [];
                if (poiLayer) {
                    poiLayer.clearLayers();
                }

                for (var i = 0,
                    j = points.length; i < j; i++) {
                    var item = points[i];
                    //   if (showPoi(item, zoom)) {

                    // var w = 50;
                    //var h = 60;

                    var w = 28;
                    var h = 42;

                    if (currentZoom === 16) {
                        w = w * zoomFactor;
                        h = h * zoomFactor;
                    }

                    /*
                     var icon = "",
                     iconHtml = "";

                     if (item.recommended) {
                     icon = "rec_tapped_poi";
                     }
                     if (item.favourited) {
                     icon = "fav_tapped_poi";
                     }

                     if (icon) {
                     iconHtml = '<img style="width:15px;height:15px;position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-7px;top:-6px" src="images/' + icon + '.png">';
                     }
                     */

                    var pinIcon = "";

                    if (item.color == "blue") {
                        pinIcon = "mapMarkerBlue";
                    }
                    if (item.color == "green") {
                        pinIcon = "mapMarkerGreen";
                    }
                    if (item.color == "purple") {
                        pinIcon = "mapMarkerPurple";
                    }
                    var myIcon = L.divIcon({
                        iconSize : [w, h],
                        iconAnchor : [(w / 2), h],
                        className : "testclass",
                        html : '<img style="width:' + w + 'px;height:' + h + 'px" src="images/poi_icons/' + pinIcon + '.png">'
                    });
                    /*
                    poiArray.push(L.marker([item.lat, item.lon], {
                        icon : myIcon,
                        item : item,
                        zIndexOffset : 2000
                    }).on("click", onClick));
                    //   }
                    */
                    poiArray.push(L.marker([item.lat, item.lon], {
                        icon : myIcon,
                        item : item                           
                    }).bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup."));                        

                };

                poiLayer = L.layerGroup(poiArray);

                poiLayer.addTo(map);
            }

            addPois(currentZoom);

            //var currentZoom = 12;
            var currentZoom = 16;
            map.on('zoomend', function(e) {

                var z = map.getZoom();

                if (currentZoom != z) {
                    currentZoom = z;

                    addPois(z);
                }
            });
            function updateIndicator(e) {
                indicatorMarker.setLatLng([e.lat, e.lon]);

                indicatorMarker.setIcon(L.icon({
                    iconUrl : "images/gps_indicator_" + 'med' + ".png",
                    iconRetinaUrl : "images/gps_indicator_" + 'med' + ".png",
                    iconSize : [140, 140],
                    iconAnchor : [70, 70]
                }));
            }


            Ti.App.addEventListener("app:setCurrentPos", function(e) {
                if (e) {
                    updateIndicator(e);
                }
            });
            Ti.App.addEventListener("app:addPoints", function(e) {

                if (e.points) {
                    Ti.API.info(e.points);
                    points = e.points;
                    addPois(currentZoom);
                }
            });


        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet doesn`t allow to open more than one popup at same time.
You need to override L.Map like this:

```
L.Map = L.Map.extend({
        openPopup: function(popup) {

            //this.closePopup();
            this._popup = popup;

            return this.addLayer(popup).fire('popupopen', {
                popup: this._popup
            });
        }
    });
```

But be careful with this trick, because you may make your map too messy with popups.